# What would a Windows 10 upgrade break on my GD8000?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, rugged

I have a GD8000 with Windows 7, a laptop with features including a touch screen, GPS integration and mapping software, and hardware and software support for Gobi (may be called Goobi now), which is a meta-[data plan] that finds who has the strongest signal and then resells you bandwidth from whoever has the strongest signal.

What, if anything, will I break if I upgrade to Windows 10, either specifically in what is outlined above, or in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check Windows 10 upgrade compatibility, follow these steps:

1. Download and install KB3035583 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035583) to get the Get Windows 10 app
2. In the Get Windows 10 app, click menu (stack of three lines) and then select **Check your PC**
3. Review the list of potential compatibility issues. Separate categories are listed for devices and apps.